# Ternary operator with more than 1 condition check

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I have a scenario where in order to assign a value to a variable I need to check more than 1 condition, is it possible to chain the conditions.

Below is just a sample format how my code looks

```
Result = (isUser == true && (ResultId == 1 || ResultId == 2 )) ? "Pass" : r.Result,
```

If condition `(isUser == true && (ResultId == 1 || ResultId == 2 ))` is met then I am saying `Result = "Pass"` else I am assigning value from `r.Result`.

In the same way I want to check another condition `(isUser == True && (ResultId == 5))` then I want to say `Result = "Absent"`

Comment: I would suggest that an `if`/`else if`/`else` pattern would be easier to read versus nested ternary operators.

Comment: You may also want to skip the explicit test for true, `== true` is not needed as `isUser` is already a bool.

Comment: I agree with the above, this code is just not readable. Coming back to this code in the future, you'll ask yourself what does this even mean. Definitely go with an if/else or a default value and an if like `Result = r.Result; if (...) Result = "Pass";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this

```
Result = isUser && (ResultId == 1 || ResultId == 2 ) ?
 "Pass" : isUser && ResultId == 5 ? "Absent" : r.result;
```

Comment: What if `isUser` is false and `ResultId` is 5?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't see his conditions clearly!, I have just edited the post, thanks

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, this is getting way too complex for the ternary operator. If you have C#8 then you can use it in combination with the expression form of `switch`. Something like:

```
Result = isUser ? ResultId switch
{
    1 => "Pass",
    2 => "Pass",
    5 => "Absent",
    _ => r.Result
}
: r.Result;
```